# Webpack - Import node module as though it was a normal folder

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a JS app which is importing a custom node_module with helper functions etc. I'd like to import these functions using ES6 imports like so:

```
import exampleHelper from 'mycustommodule/helpers/foo'
```

and have Webpack just import this file as though it was any other include in the app. ie Use the same babelrc, webpack config, package.json as the existing app.

At the moment none of the imports in the custom module are resolving.

I've looked into Webpack externals but I can't work out if they are what I'm looking for. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: create an alias, that will tell webpack on how to resolve that path

Comment: @PlayMa256 Unfortunately creating an alias means that the mycustommodule can't resolve dependencies defined in the parent package.json.